# Using Javascript to make an image appear from an IF Statement

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement

I basically want an image to appear if a  car is chosen in the drop down.Every time I alter the code the if statements stop working and the image never appears. I'm new to coding and am not sure how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<script src="Script\configurator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a> First Select a Car Make </a>
<form name="CarConfigurator">
<select name="Car_make" onchange="Transmission(this.value);">
  <option value=" " selected="selected">None</option>
  <option value="1">Audi RS6</option>
  <option value="2">BMW M4</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes C63 AMG</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <br>

 <select name="A_M" >
<option value="0" selected="selected">None</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Automatic</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Manual</option>

</select>

</form>
```

Javascript

```
function Transmission(Car) {

  var make = document.CarConfigurator.A_M;

  make.options.length = 0;

  if (Car == "1") {

    make.options[make.options.length] = new Option('Automatic', '1');

    make.options[make.options.length] = new Option

      ('Manual', '2');

  }

  if (Car == "2") {

    make.options[make.options.length] = new Option('Manual', '2');


  }

  if (Car == "3") {

    make.options[make.options.length] = new Option('Automatic', '3');

  }


}
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to images in your code. Also, please clarify what you mean by "the if statements stop working".

Comment: Are you sure `onchange="Transmission(this.value);" works?` I mean, everytime you select new value the `Transmission()` called?

Comment: I was just looking for someone to leave an example of what sort of code I would need to enter and where I would need to enter it. And im sure that onchange="Transmission(this.value);" works.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I was just wondering if it would be possible to have a button that would change the color of the car as well. I have pictures of the exact same car in different colors but just not sure how to add a button that changes them once the car make and transmission has been chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change some of your code, because I can't use it. Try this.

```
<form name="CarConfigurator">
<select name="Car_make">
  <option value="" selected="selected">None</option>
  <option value="1">Audi RS6</option>
  <option value="2">BMW M4</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes C63 AMG</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <br>

 <select name="A_M" >
<option value="0" selected="selected">None</option>
<option value="1">Automatic</option>
<option value="2">Manual</option>

</select>

</form>

 <br>
 <br>

<img id="carImage" style="width:500px">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
    function transmission(car, option) {

    if (car == "1" && option == "1") { // Audi RS6 | Automatic
      $("#carImage").attr('src',"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Audi_RS6_-_Mondial_de_l'Automobile_de_Paris_2014_-_001.jpg/280px-Audi_RS6_-_Mondial_de_l'Automobile_de_Paris_2014_-_001.jpg");

    } else if (car =="2" && option == "2") { // BMW M4 | Manual
      $("#carImage").attr('src',"http://buyersguide.caranddriver.com/media/assets/submodel/7774.jpg");

    } else if (car == "3" && option == "1") { // Mercedes C63 AMG | Automatic
      $("#carImage").attr('src',"http://images.cdn.autocar.co.uk/sites/autocar.co.uk/files/styles/gallery_slide/public/mercedes-benz-c63-amg-1.jpg?itok=yHBoS8gg");

    } else {
      $("#carImage").attr('src',"");

    }

    }

    $("select").on("change",function(){
      var selectCar = $("select[name=Car_make]");
      var selectCarOption = $("select[name=A_M]");
      transmission(selectCar.val(), selectCarOption.val());
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I was just wondering if it would be possible to have a button that would change the color of the car as well. I have pictures of the exact same car in different colors but just not sure how to add a button that changes them once the car make and transmission has been chosen.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: How would I got about this?

Comment: You should create new question for it. Because the answer not related for current question.

Comment: so a new function altogether?